# The definite number of the rows as per the definite parameters in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, row, case

I need to get all rows if number is NULL or to get number rows.

This is my code so far.

```
  CASE
   WHEN value IS NOT NULL THEN SELECT FIRST number * FROM MYTABLE
  END
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am confused with your statement and your question, it is not clear:

> I need to get all rows if `number` is NULL or to get `number` rows

And your query doesn't match with your question. So i've broken down your query and your question.

1. You can't use `case` for call multiple column, `case` only return single column. And 
   don't forget to add parentheses or it will be an error.

Your query should be :

```
CASE
   WHEN value IS NOT NULL THEN (SELECT number  FROM MYTABLE)
END
```

2. I assume you want to check `number` null with condition `value` not null.

Your query should be :

```
CASE
   WHEN value IS NOT NULL THEN 
   (SELECT case when number is null then 0 else number end FROM MYTABLE)
END
```

Because you are using Oracle you can use `NVL` you can read [Null Value Here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php)

```
CASE
   WHEN value IS NOT NULL THEN 
   (SELECT NVL(number, 0) FROM MYTABLE)
END
```

3. You want to get number row? Get confusing here. i assume you want to count from 
   condition where value not null then do count in the number. You can read [Count Here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/count.php)

Your query should be :

```
CASE
   WHEN value IS NOT NULL THEN (SELECT count(number) FROM MYTABLE)
END
```

All this query can return

> error more than one row returned by a subquery

so i prefer you do join than do `subquery` here. You can read [About Join Here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/joins.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where <number> is null or
     rownum <= <number>;
```

It is unclear to me why your sample code has both `number` and `value`.